# How to check if PHP session with $ssid is alive?

Tags: php, session

Is there some way in PHP to see if session with a specific SSID is alive?

I need to check if a list of various SSIDs is still alive.

I know I could look in `session.save_path` (/tmp)  but how the session is stored is dependent upon  `session.save_handler`/`session.serialize_handler` and I would prefer something which does not abuse this PHP internals.

Comment: It was designed to only deal with the session when its in use via a request...so you have to abuse the internals to check for a particular ssid when you don't get a request from it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
session_id($ssid);
session_start();
```

and then reaching for some data expected in the `$_SESSION`?

Alternatively, you can implement your own [handling](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). (see examples)

Comment: If the $_SESSION is not an empty array after session_start() the session is still alive (with this solution)

Comment: `session_start()` may send headers and does not work if a session has already been started. 
So I would need to 1) add a dummy entry to every session, just have something that i can expect 2) check if the current session is active 3) session_cache_limiter('') 4) close the current session 5) session_id, session_start, check for the expected data and destroy 6) restore session_cache_limiter, session_id() and start my old session again. 
A lot of stuff that also might go wrong, but it could work....

Comment: However `session_start()` has to be used _before_ anything is output to the browser, I don't think it sends anything by itself. On the other hand, if you want something not affecting the current session, I'd be looking for custom session handling or at least simple saving timestamps with every request and handling those.

Comment: according to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) it may send headers: 
 Note:
This function sends out several HTTP headers depending on the configuration. See session_cache_limiter() to customize these headers.